# Elementos repetidos em uma matriz

Tags: java, array, matriz

Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo que ache elementos repetidos em uma matriz qualquer mas não sei como. O algoritmo não deve verificar a repetição só nas linhas ou colunas, e sim na matriz toda (isso que me parece ser o mais complicado).

Alguém poderia dar uma dica de como implementar isso?

Comment: Você já tem algum código de suas tentativas? Se sim, poderia compartilhar conosco?

Comment: Não tenho. Não consegui pensar em alguma maneira de cada elemento ser comparado com todos os outros da matriz. A única coisa que pensei foi em ordenar as linhas e colunas em ordem crescente, aí caso tenha elemento repetido eles vão ficar em posições consecutivas e aí daria pra fazer uma verificação do tipo x == x+1. Mas não consegui implementar assim e achei que teria algum jeito mais simples.

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 1):

Solução dada em pergunta similar em outro site da rede (SOen) [Finding repeats in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351134/finding-repeats-in-a-2d-array)

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[][] ia = new int[3][3];
        ia[0][0] = 1;
        ia[0][2] = 1;
        ia[0][2] = 1;
        ia[1][0] = 4;
        ia[1][3] = 4;
        ia[1][2] = 2;
        ia[2][0] = 5;
        ia[2][4] = 6;
        ia[2][2] = 7;
        findRepeats(ia, ia.length*ia[0].length);
    }

    public static void findRepeats(int [][] num, int size)
{
    int findNum;
    int total = 1, row = 0, col = 0;
    int [] check = new int[size];
    while(row < num.length && col < num[0].length)
    {
        //Set to number
        findNum = num[row][col];
      //Cycle array to set next number
        if(col < num[0].length-1)
            col++;
        else
        {
            row++;      //Go to next row if no more columns
            col = 0;    //Reset column number
        }
        //Loop through whole array to find repeats
        for(int i = row; i < num.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = col; j < num[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(num[i][j] == findNum) {
                    total++;
                     //Cycle array to set next number
                      if(col < num[0].length-1)
                          col++;
                      else
                      {
                           row++;      //Go to next row if no more columns
                           col = 0;    //Reset column number
                      }
                      if(row < num.length - 1 && col < num[0].length -1)
                         num[i][j] = num[row][col];
                }
            }
        }


        //Display total repeats
        System.out.println("Number " + findNum + " appears " + total + " times.");
        total = 1;
    }
}
}
```

Funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/Ofz715)

Comment: verdade, Irei atualiza a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Para percorrer uma matriz você precisa de um `for` dentro de um `for`, logo, uma possível solução é percorrer a matriz e comparar cada elemento percorrendo novamente a matriz. Logo, você terá 4 `for`s aninhados, sendo que os dois mais externos estão percorrendo a matriz pela primeira vez, e os dois mais internos estão pegando o elemento da iteração externa da matriz e comparando elemento a elemento da iteração interna.

Para aumentar o desempenho da sua comparação, os dois `for`s mais internos não precisam começar do elemento `[0][0]`, a iteração pode começar a partir do elemento atual da iteração mais externa. Ao encontrar um elemento repetido você armazena esse valor em um `ArrayList` e continua a iteração mais externa.

Assim:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Matriz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matriz = new int[][]{
                {1,2,3,4},
                {3,4,5,6},
                {6,7,8,9}};
        List<Integer> repetidos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //percorre a matriz, elemento por elemento
        for(int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
            proximoElemento:
            for(int j=0; j<matriz[i].length; j++) {
                //caso elemento já foi marcado como repetido
                //continua para a próxima iteração
                if(repetidos.contains(matriz[i][j])) continue proximoElemento;

                //percorre novamente a matriz, elemento por elemento
                //começando do elemento atual da iteração mais externa 
                for(int i2=i; i2<matriz.length; i2++) {
                    for(int j2=0; j2<matriz[i2].length; j2++) {
                        //não se compara com ele mesmo
                        if(i==i2 && j==j2) break;
                        //achamos um repetido, armazena e 
                        //continua para a próxima iteração 
                        if(matriz[i][j] == matriz[i2][j2]) {
                            repetidos.add(matriz[i][j]);
                            continue proximoElemento;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //exibe os elementos encontrados repetidos ao menos uma vez
        for(int r: repetidos) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> 3
>   4
>   6

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/FylRoQ)

Comment: Não entendi o por quê do i2 ser inicializado como i. Se ele fosse inicializado como 0 o algoritmo funcionaria também, certo?

Comment: @Chittolina certo, também funcionaria, mas é uma otimização que eu fiz para que os `for`s internos somente percorram os elementos que ainda não foram percorridos pelos `for`s externos. Isso resulta em um número menor de iterações. Para um exemplo minúsculo como o que eu escrevi não faz muita diferença, mas como eu não sei quantos elementos tem a sua matriz preferi otimizar (pelo menos um pouquinho) o meu código.